# Element not being added to list

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

```
(defparameter *todo* '("Conquer the world" "Bake cake"))

(defun how-many-items (list)
  if (list
      (1+ (how-many-items (cdr list)))
     0))

(defun add-item (item)
  (cons item *todo*)) ; Attempt to add an item to the todo list

(princ (how-many-items *todo*))
(princ '#\newline)
(add-item "Write a book")
(princ (how-many-items *todo*))
(princ '#\newline)
(princ (cdr *todo*))
(princ '#\newline)
```

I'm still learning Lisp but I can't understand why the size of the list doesn't add when I supposedly add the item "Write a book" to it, the cdr call returns "Bake Cake" and the number of items is always two.

The output is:

```
2
2
(Bake cake)
```

Comment: *cons* does not modify its arguments. You may use *push* instead. See http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_push.htm

Comment: Oh I get it, thanks! I also tried to re-defparameter and it now works. My doubt is now, then, if it's clean or not to defparameter more than once. I feel like it's not okay, but I'm not sure.

Comment: You can reuse *defparameter* more than once (unlike *defvar*), but you would usually write something like (setf \*todo\* (cons "blabla" \*todo\*)), or better in this case, (push "blabla" \*todo\*).

Comment: By the way, if you are learning Lisp, I suggest you download the Hyperspec (see [here](ftp://ftp.lispworks.com/pub/software_tools/reference/)), if you don't have it already. It's exactly the ANSI Common Lisp standard, translated to HTML.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that `cons` is non-destructive. This means that even though you're adding an item to the item to the list that `*todo*` contains, you're not modifying `*todo*`

```
> (defparameter x '(1 2 3))
  (1 2 3)
> (cons 1 x)
  (1 1 2 3)
> x
  (1 2 3)
```

See? No modification.

Instead use `push`. It does modify its parameters.

```
> (defparameter x '(1 2 3))
  (1 2 3)
> (push 1 x)
  (1 1 2 3)
> x
  (1 1 2 3)
```

You can think of push like this

```
(push x 1) === (setf x (cons 1 x))
```

In fact, it's a macro that expands to just this in some implementations.

Comment: According to the standard, "The effect of (push item place) is equivalent to (setf place (cons item place)) except that the subforms of place are evaluated only once, and item is evaluated before place." See the notes [here](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_push.htm).

Answer (score 2):

Your output can't be real, since your function has wrong syntax.

```
(defun how-many-items (list)
  if (list
      (1+ (how-many-items (cdr list)))
     0))

CL-USER 20 > (how-many-items '(1 2))

Error: The variable IF is unbound.
```

Comment: Of course, it should be (defun how-many-items (list) (if (consp list) (1+ (how-many-items (cdr list))) 0))